# Using multiline uniq output as input for grep

Tags: macos, bash, unix, scripting, sh

I'm using the following line to print the list of users who are logged in more than once (edit) I just realized this doesn't actually work):

```
who | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+' | sort | uniq
```

Problem is, I want to only print the users whose names also exist within a text file. I'm relatively new to scripting (and Unix in general) so maybe I'm just being a huge dummy, but by my reasoning, the easiest way to do this would be to use the output of `uniq` as input for this line I found in another answer:

```
grep -Fxq "$FILENAME" blacklist.txt
```

Of course, I need to replace the `"$FILENAME"` with the output of `uniq`, but I can't for the life of me work out *how* to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
who | grep -Eo '^[^ ]+' | sort | uniq | grep -w "$(cat blacklist.txt | xargs | sed 's| |\\\||g')"
```

Where my blacklist.txt has one userid per line

This command basically separates the blacklist from

```
name1
name2
name3
```

to `name1\|name2\|name3` so that you can grep for just these words.